# Rails 3 ActiveAdmin. Does anybody know how to set ok, warning and error colors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm creating an app that's supposed to show the Open Balance, if the customer has a balance, it's supposed to be displayed with red background.

So I have this

```
sidebar "Account Balance", :only => :show do
  attributes_table_for invoice do
    row("Invoice Total") {number_to_currency invoice.total}
    row("Amount Paid") {number_to_currency invoice.amount_paid}
    row("Open Balance") {number_to_currency invoice.open_balance}
  end
end
```

I'm trying to add colors, but I can't find how in the activeadmin documentation.

There is a tutorial, though, that kinda explains how to add colors (using the ActiveAdmin css [i don't want to mess with CSS if there is something in ActiveAdmin that I can use]) but I haven't been able to implement it on my app. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/create-beautiful-administration-interfaces-with-active-admin/

Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not misreading the documentation this should work:

```
sidebar "Account Balance", :only => :show do
  attributes_table_for invoice do
    row("Invoice Total") { content_tag(:span, number_to_currency(invoice.total), :class => invoide.total < 0 ? "negative" : "positive" }
  end
end
```

You will end up with a `<span class="negative">-15$</span>` you can then style through CSS

Comment: yeah but I don't want to add any CSS if there is existing CSS that will work fine. upon paying a little bit more attention to that tutorial, i came up with this and it worked: `row("LAX Open Balance") {status_tag (invoice.lax_is_paid ? (number_to_currency invoice.lax_open_balance) : (number_to_currency invoice.lax_open_balance)), (invoice.lax_is_paid ? :ok : :error)}`

Comment: Seriously: I would go with CSS. You are just abusing the status_tag (that gets implicit CSS styling). You could just find out what classes :ok and :error are in CSS and use those for the <span>

Comment: :ok and :error just use "ok" and "error" classes. It's also worth noting that whatever you use as the status message becomes a class. (Where in the docs did you find this, though? Doesn't seem to be in the current version.)

Comment: Can't recall exactly but from the link the OP posted it seems like the block that's passed to row is just regular rails code so you can just put a content tag in there.

Answer (score 1):

`row("LAX Open Balance") {status_tag (invoice.lax_is_paid ? (number_to_currency invoice.lax_open_balance) : (number_to_currency invoice.lax_open_balance)), (invoice.lax_is_paid ? :ok : :error)}`